# PHP/MySQL: how to access an array value from a mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have a field value  in a mySQL table that I save into a variable called "$mp3".

If I echo this variable, I get this:

```
a:3:{s:4:"file";s:114:"/home/www/xxxxx/web/admin/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/table3_podcast_20141.mp3";s:3:"url";s:92:"http://www.xxxx.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/table3_podcast_20141.mp3";s:5:"error";b:0;}
```

How should I complete my variable in order to only retrieve this part of the array (whatever its content):

```
http://www.xxxx.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/table3_podcast_20141.mp3
```

Thank you!

Comment: This is a serialized string read [*unserialize*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That value is a [serialized](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) storage of a PHP array.

To reconstruct the array you need to use [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php):

```
$data = unserialize($mp3);
$url = $mp3['url'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll accept this answer in a few minutes (when the system allows me to do so)